# Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Rename - SQL DB Issues

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012

I set up a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine exactly the way we want it. I shut down the instance, made a copy of the .vhdx virtual drive, then spun up a new VM and attached the copy of the drive.

I started up the new VM and everything worked properly. Then I proceeded to run SysPrep on the new VM so it wouldn't clash with the original and I could run them both at the same time.

After running Sysprep I had to enter a CD-Key when I powered up the instance (expected behavior) and had to create an account for the new VM.

SQL Server Express was still installed and I was able to connect. However, whenever I try to expand a database I get an error message `The database [DbName] is not accessible. (Object Explorer)`

I also noticed that the SQL users I had created are now gone.

Does anyone know why this happened or how to recover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The machine name gets changed during sysprep and SQL Server needs to be manually made aware of this.  Try running this with `sysadmin` privileges:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name\instancename>;
GO
sp_addserver <new_name\instancename>, local;
GO
```

and then restart the SQL Instance.  For SQL Express you will most likely need to replace `instancename` with `sqlexpress`.

Here is the [**TechNet article**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx) explaining renaming a host.

Comment: I was able to log in as `sa` and run your recommended stored procedures to rename the instance. I still had the same issue when I use Windows Authentication and try to explore the database. The DBs show up, but when you go to expand they throw the error. There are only 2 users listed in the Security section. However, I logged in as `sa` and could explore everything and see all the users. Simply added a new user with the correct machine name with `sysadmin` privileges and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam The problem with Windows Authentication is probably also related to sysprepping the new machine.  Windows Logins are identified by a SID (a unique security identifier) that would have changed during sysprep thus orphaning the logins.